# Arithmetic comparison does not work in Bash

Tags: bash

So, I have a script for moving files from one directory to another. I want to check whether the moving was successful or not, so I use this block of  code:

```
...
mv "${!i}" "$dirname" 2>/dev/null
echo $?    # Check MV exit code
if (( $?==1 ))
then
...
```

The problem is that whether moving was successful or not, `then` does not work. If I do this instead

```
if (( $?==0 ))
```

it instead works in any case. I have read that it may be because `$?` is treated like a string, and strings have `0` value. However, if I change it to this

```
if (( $?=="1" ))
```

it does not work either. I have tried using `[[ ... ]]` and `[ ... ]` instead of `(( ... ))`, and `-eq` instead of `==`, removing and adding spaces, adding and removing quotes, but nothing worked.

What am  I doing wrong? Maybe there is another way of responding to certain exit code?

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but you should be comparing `$?` to `0`, not to `1`. `0` denotes success; any non-zero value denotes failure. A command can fail and set `$?` to `2`. (`mv` probably doesn't do this, but it's a good habit.)

Comment: Hmm. It sounds like you're expecting `$?` to be `1` on success. It's not clear whether that's the case, because you haven't told us exactly what "does not work" means. Please update your question to clarify that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
echo $?
if (( $?==1 ))
```

The first `echo $?` will echo the return value of your `mv` command;  however, in the if statement, using `$?` again will give you the return value of the `echo` command!  `$?` is always the return value of the *last* command. The last command is the echo and it is always succeeding so you are always getting a 0 return value in that if statement.

What you should do instead is save the value into a variable and then compare things to that variable:

```
mv "${!i}" "$dirname" 2>/dev/null
ret_val=$?
echo ${ret_val}
if (( ${ret_val}==1 ))
```

Comment: This is a great early answer! As an aside, though -- rather than backticks for multi-line code blocks, please consider using four-space indents (as created by selecting a multi-line span and clicking `{}`); that way you get syntax highlighting for your content, and otherwise somewhat cleaner formatting.

Comment: Please note that the logical comparison can be specified without the `$` as follows:
`if (( RV == 1 )) `.

Comment: BTW, I recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names (e.g. `rv` instead of `RV`). There are a lot of all-caps variables that have special meanings to the shell, system, etc, and if you use one of those for something else... bad things can happen. I don't think `RV` has any special function (yet!), but avoiding all-caps names is easier and safer than trying to remember them all.

Comment: Oh, no. How could I forget that **echo** also returns exit code? Probably my dumbest mistake ever (after using **=** instead of **==** in comparisons in C/C++, of course).

Thank you, anyway. I wonder how much time I would struggle without help of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the exit status of your command directly:

```
if mv "${!i}" "$dirname" 2>/dev/null; then
    # Code for successful move
else
    # Code for unsuccessful move
fi
```

Or, to keep the happy path less indented:

```
if ! mv "${!i}" "$dirname" 2>/dev/null; then
    # Code for unsuccessful move
    return 1 # Or maybe exit 1 if in a script, not a function
fi
# Code for successful move
```

As for how the exit status of `echo` messes up your code, [Tyler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52673688/3266847) has that covered.